# How to add a selected UITableViewController value to a previous UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

[image]

User clicks on "Remote" button and then the following UITableViewController loads up:

[image]

The user then selects any value upon which I call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to go back again to the previous UITableViewController (screen shot 1).

How do I add the selected value to the UITableViewController?

I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `remote recipients table view controller`, you have the Array with which you are loading the table (say `myTestArray`). Keep it as a property. And also have a NSInteger property (say `selectedRow`) which will identify which row user selected. And when you go back to the `add recipient table view controller`, you can know which row was selected by

```
[remoteRecipientsController.myTestArray objectAtIndex:remoteRecipientsController.selectedRow];
```

Or use delegates. Upon row selection the remote recipients will give a call back telling which row was selected.

Update:
If you dont have access to the view controller, use delegates.

You can get both array and the selected row in the delegate method, something as follows:

```
-(void) remoteRecipient:(RemoteRecipientController *) remoteRecipientController didSelectRow:(NSInteger) row {
// Get the selected row
... = [remoteRecipientController.myTestArray objectAtIndex:row ];
}
```

Or you can also configure the delegate to just return the selected row (as your string), something as follows:

```
-(void) remoteRecipient:(RemoteRecipientController *) remoteRecipientController didSelectRow:(NSString *) selectedRecipient {

}
```

Ofcourse, In this case you need to make remote recipient controller pass the selected row as NSString in the delegate.

Comment: yes but I would not have access to remote view controller in my "add recipient" controller.

Comment: Use delegates if you dont have access to the view controller (i am assuming you are using xib to create views).